# How to use Google Analytics to find the number of sessions with a specific event on a collection of pages?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics-events, shopping-cart, enhanced-ecommerce

I want to find the number of sessions in which "Add to Cart" event happened in a group of pages like the Product page, collection page, and search pages.

I am willing to use the enhanced e-commerce event, "Added Product" which is fired whenever an Add to Cart happens.

Comment: If you are using ecommerce -> https://electricenjin.com/blog/how-to-use-google-analytics-shopping-behavior-reports

Comment: I don't think my answer would be present in shopping behavior reports, I want to find number of sessions in which an event with event Action="Added Product" was fired on collection pages.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming here that "Add to Cart" is an Event Action that would be listed in the Behavior > Events reports.

The easiest way to get at this from within Google Analytics is a sequence segment. Your session count will come from inside the segment builder, not from a report.

To create the segment, open the segment panel and add a new segment. Choose the Sequences advanced option at the bottom of the list on the left and create a one-step sequence. Keep the default "Include Sessions" and "Any user interaction" filtration options.

Your Step 1 will start with `Event Action exactly matches "Add to Cart"`. Click "and" to create a second condition for the same hit, and set the appropriate Page condition. In the screenshot below I've set a regex for pages matching `/product/|/search/|/collection/` but, of course, what you need will depend on your URL structure.

[image: Screenshot of segment builder with 2-condition single-step sequence]

As you enter the filter conditions, the numbers on the right side of the panel for matching users and sessions may update live, or you may need to save the segment and then re-open its Edit panel to see them. It will show you how many sessions included Add to Cart on your specified pages, within the date range you are set to when you open the segment Edit screen.

One note: if your date range includes over 500,000 sessions, the data for the segment may be sampled. You can get the most accurate numbers by looking at date ranges containing fewer than 500,000 sessions.